# Android Permissions should be asked on startup or only when needed?

Tags: android

I have built an app that use different kind of permissions like location, contacts etc.
Not all the permissions are used by all the users, instead each user only needs the permissions related to the features he/she is using it.

My question, should I ask all the permission on startup for all users or can I add them gradually while using the app and only when needed?

Thanks

Comment: Better to ask only when needed, asking a lot of permissions on initial app startup is not something I'd like as an app user.

Comment: exactly. I needed to ask to be sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user doesn't know why they need to accept a specific permisson, they may be suspicious and refuse (eg. camera).
If they click on a functionnality like 'Scan code' they will know why they are being asked for that permission and accept.

If you asked beforehand and the user refused, when you get to the part where you need that permission, it won't work. This is why they changed it to dynamic permissions in Android 6.